Avoid auto focus after bottom sheet close
I have this weird behavior where I have a PageView with screen A and screen B. screen A has a textfield that unfocuses on tap outside. screen B has actions that show bottom sheets. If I type something in textfield of screen A, tap outside to unfocus, go to screen B, open a bottom sheet, once I close that bottom sheet the text field from screen A gets focused and the keyboard appears even though it should have been unfocused and it is not even on the screen anyways (screens have AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin)
How do I stop this behavior from happening

dunno about ur code, check have u dispos() the textfield or not. Anyway have a suggestion, add this line after closing the bottom sheet (FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();)

@JBJason I am using the showModalBottomSheet function but can't find a callback that gets called on close

can you provide us the code which reproduce this issue?

kindly share your code if u still didn't get it done
